# Entity Framework Cannot Delete Parent Entry When Child Has Foreign Key With WillCascadeOnDelete(false)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Why I cannot delete the parent entry while the child of it is set with `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` on the foreign key?

This is the parent:

```
public class EA_Client
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Client Id")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Id")]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client Name")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public virtual AlvinCMSExtension.Models.UserProfile User { get; set; }

    public EA_Client()
    {
        UserId = 0;
        ClientName = "";
    }
}
```

This is the child :

```
public class EA_Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Order Id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client Id")]
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Supplier Id")]
    public int? SupplierId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Total Amount To Pay")]
    public decimal TotalAmountToPay { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Order Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EA_OrderStatus> OrderStatuses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EA_OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual EA_Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual EA_Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    public EA_Order()
    {
        ClientId = null;
        SupplierId = null;
        TotalAmountToPay = 0;
        OrderTime = DateTime.Now;
        Description = "";
    }
}
```

This is the model builder for the child :

```
        mb.Entity<EA_Order>().HasOptional<EA_Client>(m => m.Client).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ClientId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        mb.Entity<EA_Order>().HasOptional<EA_Supplier>(m => m.Supplier).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.SupplierId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        mb.Entity<EA_Order>().HasMany<EA_OrderStatus>(m => m.OrderStatuses);
        mb.Entity<EA_Order>().HasMany<EA_OrderDetail>(m => m.OrderDetails);
```

Everytime I tried to delete the parent (EA_Client), this error occurs :

> {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_EAccounting.EA_Order_EAccounting.EA_Client_ClientId\". The conflict occurred in database \"EAccountingDB\", table \"EAccounting.EA_Order\", column 'ClientId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

How to fix this? I want to be able to delete the parent (EA_Client) since the parent is optional, means it is ok to have the child (EA_Order) to be orphanage entry.

Comment: You have that Id in your child table, you should set it to null and then delete the order

Comment: This will be so messy because I need to set null to my other entities as well that have optional foreign key to EA_Client. Is there a way to make it automatic?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `WillCascadeOnDelete` should be specified for parent entity, not for child. Also if dependency is optional (as you have) default behavior should be keeping children on parent removing. Did you try just remove your `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` and delete `Client` entity?

**Update:**

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) to approve my statement.

Comment: I tried WillCascadeOnDelete(true) and I able to delete the Client entity, but my EA_Order is also deleted.

Comment: But you tried it where? Still on child entity? Try to add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` for parent - Client entitty, that should make you able to delete Client without deleting Order. Don't forget to remove this method for child. If this works for you - try also to remove if from both places and it should work as you expecting, as your dependency is optional, so entity framework should update ClientId in child with null and remove Client safely.

Comment: I cannot add it on the EA_Client because the EA_Client does not have information to EA_Order, I am quite sure that adding WillCascadeOnDelete(false) to EA_Client means that if the child is deleted, then the EA_Client will not be deleted, this is the reverse of what I want.

Comment: Your EA-Order will be deleted because it has a reference to the EA_Child, you cannot delete the EA_Child without deleting the EA_Order.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx this article it won't. It also states ` If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable, Code First does not set cascade delete on the relationship, and when the principal is deleted the foreign key will be set to null.` So the same what I'm telling, just remove `WillCascadeOnDelete` from your child at all and give it a try. Also if you would like to add it to parent your could use code like this: `mb.Entity<EA_Client>().MasMany<EA_Client>().WithOptional(x => x.ClientId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

Comment: I agree with **Vladyslav**

Comment: I tried to add the code `mb.Entity<EA_Client>().HasMany<EA_Order>().WithOptional(m => m.Client)....` but that `.HasMany<EA_Order>()` causes no overload method for 0 arguments. This leaves me to specify every children entity on EA_Client, which is a lot of code for the other same situation entity. At least the problem is solved now. Well I have another problem because I have the same situation entity but the parent is from another assemble (.dll) which I cannot change.

Comment: You still could proceed with the way "remove WillCascadeOnDelete" from everywhere and that won't cause you specifying all dependencies. For parent which you can't change the only one way to go is to manually set (as I got it's supplier) SupplierId to null and only after that remove that Supplier. Also if that Supplier in external library doesn't have mentioned `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` it's deletion won't affect your Order as EF handles that as a weak dependency and will keep your child by default. Simply give it a try :)